# Trigger successhandler from ajax call when someone clicks a button

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have an ajax call which grabs data from a php file that connects to an api.  I have a success handler that receives the data from the ajax call and then loads a function from the API library.  The issue is, I want the user to click a button and then run the function inside of the success call (using the same data from the ajax call earlier).

I believe my ajax call needs to stay inside the window.onload = function(), it doesn't work if I try to run the ajax call when the user clicks the button.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hi</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js"></script>
    <script>
            function hello(){
                alert("hi");
            }
            function successHandler(data){
                screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', data, {
                    nativeDownloadStarting: hello
                    });
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "key.php",
                    data: '',
                    success: successHandler,
                    dataType: "json"
                }); 
            };


    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

Please let me know how I can do this, any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Update:**
so I have tried adjusting my code, but for some reason nothing happens anymore when I click the button.  It doesn't even shoot out my console.log confirming I had even clicked the button.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>hi</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://api.screenleap.com/js/screenleap.js"></script>
    <script>
            var dataFromServer;

            function hello(){
                alert("hi");
            }
            function successHandler(data){
                dataFromServer = data;
                console.log("data from server: ")
                console.log(dataFromServer);
            }

            window.onload = function() {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "key.php",
                    data: '',
                    success: successHandler,
                    dataType: "json"
                }); 
            };

            $("#submit").click(function(){
                console.log('clicked submit');
                if(dataFromServer)
                {   
                    console.log(datafromserver);
                    screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', dataFromServer, {
                        nativeDownloadStarting: hello
                    });
                }
            });
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit">
</body>
</html>
```

all the best,

-- 24x7

Answer (score -1):

You can store data to some global variable and on button click use same variable.

```
var dataFromServer;

function successHandler(data){
    dataFromServer = data;
}

jQuery("#submit").click(function(){
    if(dataFromServer)
    {   
        screenleap.startSharing('DEFAULT', dataFromServer, {
        nativeDownloadStarting: hello
        });
    }
});
```

Update:

Instead of window.onload use jquery onload function to populate data.

http://jsfiddle.net/ZGggK/

```
 $(function() {
            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "https://api.github.com/users/mralexgray",
                data: '',
                success: successHandler,
                dataType: "json"
            }); 
        });
```

Comment: hi thanks for getting back to me!  I have updated my question above, please let me know if I can clarify anything.